# How to connect to Oracle SQL Developer connection on a virtual machine from host machine using a different version?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, vmware

I'm using oracle sql developer on my WINDOWS XP virtual machine vers 1.5.0.52 ( a very old version). I created inside a connection ( a database) and I have many tables and my data there. Now I want to connect to this connection on my windows 11 host machine in order to get this connection and synchronize data.

This is my current connection on the virtual machine, how can I connect to it from the SQL Developer of my host machine , giving that the version of SQL developer in my host machine is a recent one (and is not the same version present in my virtual machine). How can I proceed ?

Here's a picture of my connection on the VM :

[image]

Comment: SQL Developer is an IDE. It is not a database, and you cannot connect to it in meaningful way. You may connect to the database that your old SQL Developer was connected to, but you need to expose IP address and port of your VM to the host. Then use connection details of your old SQL Developer (or use "Export connections" feature if it is available on that old one)